# I am not able to upload the github data link to Google Colab

Tags: pandas, github

what I am trying:
url ='https://github.com/Anubhav1107/Machine_Learning_A-Z/blob/master/Part%202%20-%20Regression/Section%205%20-%20Multiple%20Linear%20Regression/50_Startups.csv'

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)
```

and what I am getting:

---

> - ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>       1 url ='https://github.com/Anubhav1107/Machine_Learning_A-Z/blob/master/Part%202%20-%20Regression/Section%205%20-%20Multiple%20Linear%20Regression/50_Startups.csv'
>     ----> 2 dataset = pd.read_csv(url)
>
> 3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py
>   in read(self, nrows)    1993     def read(self, nrows=None):    1994
>   try:
>   -> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1996         except StopIteration:    1997             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
>
> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
>   75, saw 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Anubhav1107/Machine_Learning_A-Z/master/Part%202%20-%20Regression/Section%205%20-%20Multiple%20Linear%20Regression/50_Startups.csv'
```

Otherwise you'll just get the HTML, not the CSV.

Comment: @Stark_Tony You can accept or upvote the answer, if you like it.